# Elementary Field Theory: Extension Field of Degree 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm trying to do/understand the following exercise:

> "Let $E$ be a finite extension of a field $F$. If $[E:F] = 2$, show that $E$ is a splitting field of $F$."*

Background: Just beginning studying fields, I know nothing of Galois theory. Here is my reasoning so far:

$[E:F] = 2$ means that E, when viewed as a vector space over F, has dimension 2. This means that

$\beta \in E \implies \beta = b_0 + b_1 \alpha$, where $\alpha \in E \setminus F$

In other words, $E$ must not only be a finite extension but a simple extension $F(\alpha)$, where the degree of $\alpha$ over F is 2.  Did I interpret the definitions correctly here? Does $[E:F]$ imply that $E$ is such a simple extension? [Cleared up definition of a field splitting a field.]

Now, assuming the above is correct, $\alpha \in E$ implies that $\alpha^2 = c+d\alpha$, for some $c$, $d \in F$. Consider this polynomial of degree 2 in $F[x]$:

$p(x)=x^2-dx-c$

We see that:

$p(\alpha)=\alpha^2-d\alpha-c = 0$

Therefore:

$p(x) = (x-\alpha)q(x)$

Where $q(x)$ must be of degree one, i.e. a linear factor. So $E$ is a splitting field of $p(x)$. Is my reasoning correct?

<sub>*pg. 330 from Judson's Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications, freely available here http://abstract.ups.edu/download.html.</sub>

Comment: It means that $E$ splits **some** (irreducible) polynomial.

Comment: Oh thank god. I will see if I can solve it from there.
This may be a too meta of a question, but is it better form to leave my question as is or edit it now that I know that definition properly?

Comment: You can write down the polynomial, since $\alpha^2$ is a linear combination of $1$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: Hard to know, perhaps yes. You will be given a solution, but you need not look at it until you have figured it out on your own.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you meant by that last comment. I elected to alter my question because that definition isn't really the crux of the problem. Thank you for your hint though!

Comment: I assume if there is anybody around, a solution will be posted. (I can post one easily if that is wished.) But I think you prefer to figure out things yourself.

Comment: $[E:F]$ being a number doesn't imply that the extension is simple. However, in this case, we can see it must be simple because $F + \alpha F$ already has dimension $2$ over $F$, and thus $F + \alpha F \subseteq F(\alpha) \subseteq E$ implies all three vector spaces are equal.

Comment: @Hurkyl, my understanding is that $F(\alpha) = F + \alpha F$ in all cases. Is this correct?

I guess I am not seeing where our reasoning differed substantially.

Comment: @mb7744: If $F(\alpha)$ is a degree 3 extension of $F$, then $F + \alpha F$ is still only a two dimensional vector space, and thus cannot be equal to $F(\alpha)$. In fact, because $2$ doesn't divide $3$, $F + \alpha F$ can't even be a subfield of $F(\alpha)$.

Comment: Ah of course! Thank you!

Comment: Your solution is close to what I had written, down to the choice of $c$ and $d$ (but I interchanged them). Note that the splitting is $(x-\alpha)(x-(d-\alpha))$, explicitly with coefficents in $E$.